# Categorizing data in Excel

Tags: excel, finance

I'm creating a non-operating expenses sheet and I'm trying to find an easy way to sort data. Basically I want to categorize into bins. If I have a set of cells say

11
21
21
50
67
45

Is there a way to sort them so if I did something like typed a bin number into the adjacent cell I could collect them. Basically,

11 | 1
21 | 2
21 | 3
50 | 2
67 | 1
45 | 1

1 | 123
2 | 71
3 | 21

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Here we help you with **code you wrote yourself**, as per [ask]. If you need someone to create an application for you, there is http://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column A (the numbers, `11, 21, 21, 50, 67, and 45`), and the "Bin" number is in column B

Where you want `123`, `71`, `21`, you can use do this on a new range, say starting in column E (where you have the `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.)

`=SUMIF($B$1:$B$6,E1,$A$1:$A$6)`
and drag down

(Adjust the range as necessary)

[image]

Edit: Kindly explain any downvotes? I know there wasn't much given in OP, but this looked pretty simple. Should I have waited for more effort anyways?